# How to edit the end of the current page's URL in Safari on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

In Safari on iOS, imagine I am on the page at this url:

```
https://www.example.com/long-long-url/very-long/very-long-path/page-1
```

How can I quickly navigate to

```
https://www.example.com/long-long-url/very-long/very-long-path/page-2
```

The end of the url is different.

Clicking on the URL selects the whole URL, but does not scroll to the end. I can long-hold space to bring up a cursor, move it to the right of the screen, and slowly o-so-painfully slowly scroll horizontally to the end of the line. Or I can double-click the first word in the URL to select it, and drag the right-handle rightwards to get to the end before clicking again to start typing at the end, which is slightly faster.

But what's the fastest way to navigate to a page at a URL different to the current one only at the very end?

Comment: I often copy/paste it anywhere else, where there is enough space for the URL, usually Notes or Messages, I edit the end and copy again/paste/open the link, it may be quicker sometimes lol

Comment: I select the URL, then hit the right arrow to move myself to the end.

Comment: @ErniePC12 I don't have a bluetooth keyboard for my iPhone, and don't see any right arrow on the screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I think I found the fastest way to achieve this for now :

1. Select the entire URL.
2. **Cut the URL**.
3. **Paste it and the cursor should be at the end of the URL**.
4. Edit as you wish.

Here's a little example :

[image: GIF showing how to use the given technique]

Hope it'll work for you !

Comment: Yes this is definitely the fastest I know of now, and probably will be hard to beat. It's a shame that Apple has added some kind of lag between registering taps on the screen, if you tap too soon after a previous action then the Cut/Copy/Paste menu will not appear.

Answer (score 4):

To quickly edit the URL, tap on the address bar as you normally would. The whole URL will be selected.

Next, using the on-screen keyboard press and hold the spacebar.  After 1 second, you can then use the keyboard as a trackpad. Move the cursor to the end of the URL; the text will be automatically unselected.

Use the *whole* onscreen keyboard as your trackpad, not just the spacebar. You can dramatically speed up the movement of the cursor by moving diagonally across the (blanked out keys) on-screen keyboard. It seems to work like a mouse pointer with acceleration.

Make your edit and press return.

This and other useful tips for interacting with the on-screen keyboard can be found on [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/type-with-the-onscreen-keyboard-ipad997da459/ipados)

Comment: That's my current method. Moving the cursor to the end of the URL takes a minute. It's excruciatingly slow!

Comment: I made an edit that addresses this.

Comment: That's still exactly the same as what I'm already doing. It's super slow.

Comment: Swipe faster.  It should move further, faster.

Comment: Moving diagonally (e.g. from Q to enter, or from space bar to p, or from z to p) doesn't seem to move any faster than simply moving horizontally?

Comment: I had a super long URL and it worked well for me. I swiped from about the “X” position to the “P” position quickly and it went right to the end.

Comment: I just tried that! Starting the cursor using long-hold on the space bar, then **_moving left first_** (finger to the bottom left of the keyboard) then swiping super fast to the top-right of the keyboard jumps right to the end of my URL too.

Comment: I think moving left before moving right is key to making it scroll so fast that it looks like jumping. But it isn't reliable, I've tried a lot of times in a row now, and many times I succeeded to make it jump to the end, but sometimes it just scrolls like normal once the cursor reaches the right-side of the screen too. I've experimented with a few different styles: move left slowly, right quickly; left quickly, right slowly; left quickly right quickly... the last one seems the best and fastest, but none of them work every time.

Comment: is there a way to to get to the end of a search field , lets say google search in safari iphone ios, in a similar way

Answer (score 1):

After tapping on the address bar, I double tap on a word (e.g. the word “example” in example.com). This selects the word “example” instead of the entire URL. Then I tap and hold to the right of the selected word. When a little magnifier appears after a second or so, sliding the finger to the right will quickly scroll all the way to the end of the URL.

Then make the edit to get to the next page.

Comment: After tapping on the address bar, tapping on a word just (re)selects the entire contents of the address bar (which were selected as soon as the keyboard appeared after tapping on the address bar). It does not narrow the selection to the word that was tapped on. It just makes the Copy/Paste/... menu appear.

Comment: I've edited my earlier answer to double tapping on a word to trigger its selection.

Comment: Nice I didn't know about double-tapping a word to select. Looks like the rest of the method is one of the ones I'd been doing before. You can drag the right handle of the selected word before waiting for the magnifying glass to appear.